# Private VLAN on single port

Tags: networking, hp, vlan

I am trying to separate a group of computers (5 to be exact) from an entire network, but they still need to login from ad dc. Those computers are on a different floor, they have static IPs, and they are connected to an HP 1410-8g switch. The HP 1410-8g switch is connected to a port of an HP 1910-48G. The server and other computers are connected directly to the HP 1910-48G.

My question is that if I create VLAN on same the port of hp1910-48g, (the one which HP 1410-8g switch is connected), can those computers still communicate with AD DC? If it is possible, how I can do that, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you'd need to dedicate entire port on 1910-48g since 1410-8g unmanaged switch
more details here:
[How to set up 2 separate VLANs on one switch (HP v1910-48G switch)](https://serverfault.com/questions/570657/how-to-set-up-2-separate-vlans-on-one-switch-hp-v1910-48g-switch)
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426614/how-to-set-up-2-separate-vlan-on-one-switch-hp-v1910-48g-switch

Comment: thank you for your time. its worked. i add another port to vlan and connected to server's second ethernet for active directory. but new vlan can't connect inernet, now trying to fix that